# C# Reading process memory returning wrong values

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, console-application

i'm trying to read some values from process memory with multiple pointers/offsets
on my console .Net App but i'm getting the wrong last 3 values, i don't know what i'm doing wrong I've been checking the code and trying different ways for hours but still the same results.

I'm reading these values from a 64-bit process

Here's a preview from my app and cheat engine at the same time (cheat engine contains the correct values).

[image]

Here is my code for reading these pointers :

```
        Memory.OpenProcess(Data.Core.ProcessID);
        Data.Core.GameBase = (uint)Memory.BaseAddress("Game.dll");


        uint Num0 = Memory.ReadInt((int)Data.Core.GameBase + 
        (int)Data.Core.Offsets.Animation);
        uint Num1 = Memory.ReadInt((int)Num0 + (int)Data.Core.Offsets.P1);
        uint Num2 = Memory.ReadInt((int)Num1 + (int)Data.Core.Offsets.P2);
        uint Num3 = Memory.ReadInt((int)Num2 + (int)Data.Core.Offsets.P3);
        uint Num4 = Memory.ReadInt((int)Num3 + (int)Data.Core.Offsets.P4);
        uint Num5 = Memory.ReadInt((int)Num4 + (int)Data.Core.Offsets.P5);
```

ReadInt function :

```
 public uint ReadInt(int iMemoryAddress)
 {
    byte[] bBuffer = new byte[4];
    IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead;
    if (Mapi.ReadProcessMemory(this._hReadProcess, (IntPtr) iMemoryAddress, 
    bBuffer, 4U, out lpNumberOfBytesRead) == 0)
    return 0;
    return BitConverter.ToUInt32(bBuffer, 0);
 }
```

also :

```
    public uint ReadInt(int Address)
    {
        OpenProcessMemory();
        int BytesRead = 0;
        byte[] Data = new byte[4];
        ReadProcessMemory((int)PHandle, Address, Data, 4, ref BytesRead);
        CloseProcessMemory();
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(Data, 0);
    }
```

Offsets enum :

```
    public enum Offsets : uint
    {
        Animation = 0x1494198,
        P1 = 0x68,
        P2 = 0x70,
        P3 = 0x28,
        P4 = 0x378,
        P5 = 0x522,
    }
```

win api :

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr 
lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] bBuffer, uint size, out IntPtr 
lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

I've tried to add pointers and offsets using IntPtr / uint / int / Int32 for each Pointer+Offset but still the same weird values at the end.
I think i can't do more than this obviously..

Comment: Note in the screenshot with the Chat Engine attached, all/some of those pointers that work there but don't work in your program display some pointer values (the "P->..." thing) that are larger than 32 bit. Thus, try to use `IntPtr` variables (or alternatively, `long`) for handling pointer values everywhere in your program instead of using `uint`/`int`.

Answer (score 0):

If the target process is x64, then you need to also compile for x64 and you should use IntPtr for all pointers, offsets and addresses to ensure they are the correct length to accept 64 bit addresses.

For walking pointer chains you should use this function which de-references each pointer and then adds the offset for you.

```
public static IntPtr FindDMAAddy(IntPtr hProc, IntPtr ptr, int[] offsets)
{
    var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
    foreach (int i in offsets)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, buffer.Length, out var read);

        ptr = (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        ? IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)), i)
        : ptr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)), i);
    }
    return ptr;
}

var ammoAddr = FindDMAAddy(hProc, (IntPtr)(modBase + 0x10f4f4), new int[] { 0x374, 0x14, 0 });
```